# prevent child from @click vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this situation:

```
<a href="#" 
  class="btn btn-xs btn-bricky tooltips" 
  :data-id="row.id" 
  data-placement="top"
  data-original-title="Remove" 
  @click.self.stop="removeRow($event)">
       <i class="fa fa-times fa fa-white"></i>
</a>
```

Now, when I click on link it's ok, but if I click on `<i>` (which is inside of `<a>`) nothing happens (because of `@click.self.stop`).

What I would like to achieve is to trigger same method, in this case `removeRow()`, no matter if I click `<a>` or `<i>` is clicked. I need to get `data-id` attribute form ahref.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What I would like to achieve is to trigger same method, in this case removeRaw, no matter if I click `<a>` or `<i>` is clicked.

From what you say, you actually have to just remove the `.self` modifier.

Per [docs (Event Handling/Event Modifiers/`.self`)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers):

> ```
> <!-- only trigger handler if event.target is the element itself -->
> <!-- i.e. not from a child element -->
> <div v-on:click.self="doThat">...</div>
> ```

See changed code below.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    rows: [{id: 1, name: "row1"}, {id: 2, name: "row2"}]
  },
  methods: {
    removeRow($event) {
      console.log($event.currentTarget.dataset.id)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">

  <div v-for="row in rows">
     <a href="#" 
       class="btn btn-xs btn-bricky tooltips" 
       :data-id="row.id" 
       data-placement="top"
       data-original-title="Remove" 
       @click.stop="removeRow($event)">
         <i class="fa fa-times fa fa-white"></i> {{ row.name }}
     </a>
  </div>
 
</div>
```

The only modified bit in the template was `@click.self.stop="removeRow($event)"`
to `@click.stop="removeRow($event)"`.

In the JS part, I created a `rows` just to test, and added `console.log($event.currentTarget.dataset.id)` to show how to get the `id`.

Comment: Thank you. 
I'll accept your answer as correct one. 

Bhojendra Nepal helped me as well but you really put effort in it :)

Answer (score 1):

Then you don't need to use `stop` propagation or call function on `self`:

```
<a href="#" 
class="btn btn-xs btn-bricky tooltips" 
:data-id="row.id" 
data-placement="top"
data-original-title="Remove" 
@click.prevent="removeRow($event)">
       <i class="fa fa-times fa fa-white"></i>
</a>
```

`prevent` is used to prevent the default link action.

You can use [currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) instead of `target` to identify the attached element and get the href value from there.

```
$event.currentTarget.href
```

---

Alternatively, why not just to set the value in params:

```
@click.prevent="removeRow('your-value')"
```

In your method:

```
removeRow(myvalue) {
  // do whatever you want to do with myvalue
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is quite easy. use @click.stop

```
@click.stop(openUser(user))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following sample to get it to work. 
Run the code and click on the three texts, but you will only get the data-id value of the child and parent divs

```js
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 methods: {
  init($event){
   let el = $event.target.nodeName
   var id = null; 
   
   if(el == 'A'){
    id = $event.target.dataset.id
   }
   
   if(el == 'I'){
    id = $event.target.parentElement.dataset.id
   }
  
   console.log( ' id', id)
  }
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.9/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  
<a href="#" @click='init' data-id='42'> Inside A <br/>
  <i>Inside I</i>
</a>
  
</div>
```